# Change the url for the workbox runtime

Tags: workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

As of v5, workbox generates a runtime bundle which is very useful. I was not able to find a way to specify where the bundle should be. by default it is next to the service worker file, but we need it to be on a CDN. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that's not configurable in v5.

You don't mention why you need it to be on the CDN—if that's not a hard requirement, I'd suggest just keeping it alongside your service worker. [You have control](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/09/fresher-sw) over how frequently imported scripts are checked for updates if you're concerned about QPS.

Alternatively, you can set `inlineWorkboxRuntime: true` and you'll end up with a single file that contains both your service worker logic and the Workbox runtime code. If for some reason deploying two files is a problem, but one is okay, then that might help.